# Responding in thread to a slack workflow post

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

My goal is to have my bot respond in thread to a workflow post in the channel. The response will be based on what is inside of the workflow post. For example, the workflow post will contain `Topic:Canvas Data` and the bot will respond in thread. Here is my current bot script

```
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler

token = config("KEY")
app_token = config("App_Token")
app =App(token=token)

@app.message("Topic: Canvas Data")
def something(message, say):
    channel = message["channel"]
    thread_ts = message["ts"]
    text = "Hey! Here are some Canvas Data resources you can send to the client. \n \n• <https://impl.instructuremedia.com/embed/4f3edf4a-4d61-4b70-8279-963af90b207d|Canvas Data Video Overview>  \n• <https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Canvas-Data-Users/Canvas-Data-FAQ/ta-p/251184|Canvas Data FAQ> \n• <https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Admin-Guide/How-do-I-use-the-Canvas-Data-Portal-for-an-account/ta-p/261|How do I use the Canvas Data Portal for an account> \n• <https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Admin-Guide/tkb-p/admin#CanvasDataServices|Canvas Data Services Guides>"
    say(text=text, channel=channel, thread_ts=thread_ts)



def main():
   handler = SocketModeHandler(app, app_token)
   handler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have looked at the slack documenation and I think this is a modal  but I am not sure if it is or how to make a response to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.